# How i want get values in same page in fragment using nfc reader?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

When i Tag the NFC card .I got directly went at main page.But i want in the same page using fragment.
`@override`
`public void onResume() {`
`super.onResume();`
`Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();`
`String action = intent.getAction();`
`if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {`
`Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);`
`if (tag == null) {`
`nNfcNumber.setText("tag == null");`
`} else {`
`String tagInfo = "";`
`byte[] tagId = tag.getId();`
`for (int i = 0; i < tagId.length; i++) {`
`tagInfo += Integer.toHexString(tagId[i] & 0xFF) + "";`
`}`
`tagInfo += "";`
`nNfcNumber.setText(tagInfo);`
`nNFcnumber = nNfcNumber.getText().toString().trim();`
`Log.d("dfdgdfdf", " " + nNFcnumber);`
`}`
`} else {`
`}`
`}`

Comment: Do you want to access your Activity's variables from Fragment?

Comment: post what you have done so far